# VSTS NuGet Packager error: "Path cannot be null."

Tags: nuget, azure-pipelines, packager

While moving to the VSTS online builds, I'm running into the following error during my NuGet Packager step in which I package my artifacts into a nuget package based on a nuspec file in my project.

```
2016-07-28T04:24:41.7652305Z ##[error]Path cannot be null.
2016-07-28T04:24:41.7652305Z ##[error]Parameter name: path
```

My NuGet Packager step's path variable looks like this:

`*\ProjectName1.nuspec;*\ProjectName2.nuspec;`

I checked in nuget.exe 3.4.4 into my solution in the .nuget folder along with my nuget.config. I then, in advanced settings, specified this nuget.exe to be used by entering the following path as "Path to NuGet.exe"

`$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\.nuget\nuget.exe`

This didn't seem to help.

Prior to this, all other steps are working correctly and my projects are compiling without any issues.

Also, when I run nuget.exe pack command locally for these .nuspec files, the packages are created successfully.

Any input would be much appreciated. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much frustration and endless hours, I have found the solution.

Just update the My NuGet Packager step's path:

`*\ProjectName1.nuspec;*\ProjectName2.nuspec`

Note that the last ';' character has been removed.
If this character is present, the NuGet Packager template is expecting an additional string after this, which in my case was blank.

All of a sudden the error description makes complete sense.